# How to use <img src=""> in XSLT (SharePoint)

Tags: xslt, sharepoint, xslt-1.0

I am using the following code to display image using XSLT in Sharepoint. It is working fine.

```
<xsl:value-of select="@Image">
```

But this approach doesn't allow me to define width and height of image so I tried to use it like this but it didn't work.

```
<img src="{@Image}" width="100" height="100">
```

How to make it work?

Comment: What does your XML look like specifically the image attribute that you reference? What do you mean by 'didn't work'?

Answer (score 2):

Your xsl isn't well-formed. You can use

```
<img src="{@Image}" width="100" height="100" />
```

This is well-formed xhtml version.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this, & add more details to your question.

```
<xsl:variable name="img">
      <xsl:value-of select="@Image" />
</xsl:variable>
```

then;

```
<img src="$Image" width="100" height="100" />
```

More on XHTML - http://xhtml.com/en/xhtml/reference/img/